# Django, Show certain media dirs to logged in users

Tags: django

I have an Django app where users can download files that was assigned to them. How can I be sure that only the user who is assigned the file may download that file. Because its in the media dir, any one can brows there, so is there a way of letting only the relevant user download the file?

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing one year ago.
I want only relevant users can download their photos:

```
# urls.py
(r'^data/photos/(?P<path>.*)$','views.data_access'),
```

my view 'data_access' gives the photo, or a 403 page

```
# view data_access(request, path)
# [...code...]
if user_can_download:
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/jpeg")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % unicode(photo.image.name)
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected/'+ unicode(path)
        return response
else:
   return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: Ok wait, but I can still just brows to /media/etc/etc/photos/ and see the photos, any user can see them. I am getting this wrong?

Comment: [`return HttpResponseForbidden`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden) is clearer, than explicitly setting the `403`.

Comment: @Harry: nope, /data in my project is the classic /media.